# quasilinear evolution with term $uu_t$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a problem of this type:

$\begin{cases}
uu_t+au_x+bu=0,\ (x,t)\in (0,1)\times(0,T);\\
u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0, \ t\in (0,T);\\
u(x,0)=u_0(x), \ x\in (0,1).
\end{cases}$

I'd like to know if either there is a model for this problem or a method to solve it or maybe a change of variables that can transform it in a known model.

Comment: you can solve this by using the method of characteristics.

Comment: And i think you question is not complete, as you only have an initial condition, but no boundary condition.